How to write SQL query to show count of 2 variables side-by-side
I am relatively new to SQL. I have a column titled "member_casual" which indicates whether a user is a member or casual user. I am trying to query my table to get a count of all members and all casual users, shown side by side.
I've tried the following query:
SELECT COUNT (member_casual = "member") AS member_count,
FROM `ascendant-yeti-415121.cyclistic_capstone_data.divvy_data_2023`
WHERE (member_casual = "member")
UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(member_casual = "casual") AS casual_count
FROM `ascendant-yeti-415121.cyclistic_capstone_data.divvy_data_2023`
WHERE (member_casual = "casual")

That gives me the following:
Screenshot of result
I realize a union doesn't really make sense, but when I tried use the following query, it formats it the way I'm wanting, but gives me the same count for both, even though they are not the same.
SELECT COUNT (member_casual = "member") AS member_count,
COUNT (member_casual = "casual") AS casual_count
FROM `ascendant-yeti-415121.cyclistic_capstone_data.divvy_data_2023`


Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question

I figured it out. I used the following to achieve the desired result:
SELECT member_casual,
COUNT (member_casual) AS count_of_riders
FROM `ascendant-yeti-415121.cyclistic_capstone_data.divvy_data_2023`
GROUP BY member_casual


Thanks for the tip. I didn't realize I didn't need DISTINCT as well. As I said, I'm new. I will edit my query now.
